# How to compare two variables

Tags: php, html, if-statement, compare

I want to check if the line in the textfile is the same string as the $name variable. I can't find a reason why they doesn't match. The Line in the textfile is "Test01" and $name is also $Test01.

Here's the code:

```php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$lines= file('dashboard_stats.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  echo strcasecmp($name, $line);
}
```

Comment: I it' because the line break but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `var_dump($name, $line)` gives what?

Comment: From docs: `Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used`. Try `file('dashboard_stats.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`.

Comment: use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), vs looping through all values

Comment: Potential solution, `exec("grep -E  " . escapeshellarg($name) . " dashboard_stats.txt)"`... and add `\b`s to `$name`. This probably a better solution for memory.. it is not looking at new lines exclusively though.. could be rewritten for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can go around the linebreaks by trimming. This will remove all whitespaces including linebreaks at left and right from the given string.

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $trimmed = trim($line);
    echo strcasecmp($name, $trimmed);
}
```